# Getting intervals with CLP

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I would like to get the non-discontinued intervals of variable domains in a prolog environment.

For example, I have a variable X which is constrained to take some values in its domain. Let's say X has an *initial domain* `[0..20]` and it is constrained to (not) have `5`, `8`, `9` as values. So X has the new domain `[0..4, 6, 7, 10..20]`. I would like to get non-discontinued intervals in this domain as a list `[[0..4], [6,7], [10..20]]`.

In *SWI-Prolog*, using *clpfd* library when I run the following goal:

```
X in 0..20, X #\= 5, X #\= 8, X #\= 9.
```

Answer is:

```
X in 0..4\/6..7\/10..20.
```

So far so good. But I don't know how I can get this domain as a list of intervals. Is there a way to do it?

---

Solutions with other Prolog implementations and their respective CLP/FD libraries are also welcome.

Comment: You need [`fd_dom/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html#fd_dom/2) and then map the term to your preferred representation.

Comment: I don't know how to do the mapping you mentioned. 

Closest I could get was:

    `?- X in 0..20, X #\= 5,  X #\= 8, X #\= 9, fd_dom(X, Dom), Dom = T1 \/ T2 \/ T3.` 

 it is answered as 

    `Dom = 0..4\/6..7\/10..20,
    T1 = 0..4,
    T2 = 6..7,
    T3 = 10..20,
    X in 0..4\/6..7\/10..20.` 

How can I apply it, without knowing the number of continuous intervals?

Comment: Please *read* the manual! It already contains an example how to map a domain to a list of all possible values. You should be able to adopt that definition  to the representation you want.

Comment: What do you expect for single values like `X in 0..20, X #\= 5, X #\= 7, X #\= 8`

Comment: Ok, I remember seeing the part of docs with `dom_integers` definition, but I didn't pay enough attention, thinking that it was a system predicate. Now I am trying to understand the `phrase/3` predicate. Then I hope to write a customized dom_interval predicate.

Comment: The outcome I expect from `X in 0..20, X #\= 5, X #\= 7, X #\= 8` is `[[0..4], [6], [9..20]]`.

Comment: Well, it should be easy for you to convert the example in the manual.

Comment: In any case, I very much doubt that this specific representation makes much sense - compared to the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fd_dom/2`, it is possible to get the domain of the variable. Then a [DCG rule](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG) can be used to parse the domain which is in form of `L1..U1\/L2..U2\/...` .

An example DCG rule for getting domain as a list of integers is given in SWI-Prolog manual ([link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=fd_dom/2)). With a little modification it can be used to get the intervals:

```
dom_intervals(Dom, Intervals) :- phrase(dom_intervals1(Dom), Intervals).

dom_intervals1(I)           -->  {integer(I)}, [I].
dom_intervals1(L..U)        --> [L..U].
dom_intervals1(D1 \/ D2)    --> dom_intervals1(D1), dom_intervals1(D2).
```

Finally this query can be used:

`X in 0..20, X #\= 5, X #\= 8, X #\= 9, fd_dom(X, D), dom_intervals(D, Intervals).`

---

Though clpfd is not mentioned in YAP-prolog [manual](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/yap.html), it is possible to do the same with YAP-prolog too.